# How is the sign of the work done in line integral problems decided?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am having difficulty understanding the sign given by the work done in Line Integral problems. After working many problems I noticed much to my dismay that the wording seems to be inconsistent in the following aspect: Some work problems specifically say "work done by a vector field on the particle." others say "work done on a moving particle in a vector field" not really specifying who or what is doing the work, and  yet others say "work done by a particle in the vector field". You will notice that the vector field doing the work vs. the particle doing the work are used interchangeably as if it does not matter.  And yet another textbook I was referencing says work is expressed negatively in physics and positively in mathematics. I assume the meaning of by the particle vs. by the force field is just reversing the sign. But how do you decide which will be positive and which will be negative ?